# SQL Query optimization with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, query-performance

I followed the instructions from [This link](http://www.iheavy.com/2013/06/13/how-to-optimize-mysql-union-for-high-speed/)

It seems that it doesn't improve much(only 0.09 Sec improved). Is not enough, My aim is to optimize it more.

Tables

```
state: id,title,abbr
regions: id,title
regions_suburbs: region_id,suburb_id
suburbs: id,state_id,region_id,postcode
properties: id,title
```

I am trying to find any keyword inside proprety.title, suburb.title, state.abbr, state.title and suburb.postcode.

Query as below-

[Perivous] Showing rows 0 - 4 (5 total, Query took 4.7122 sec)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN p.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('project_id|',p.id) WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('suburb_id|',s.id) ELSE '0' END AS id,s.title As SuburbName,s.postcode,st.abbr,CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.propertyname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(p.propertyname,', ') END,CASE WHEN s.title IS NULL THEN'' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(s.title), ' ') END,CASE WHEN st.abbr IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(st.abbr), ' ') END,CASE WHEN s.postcode IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(s.postcode, '') END) AS SearchTerm FROM properties p LEFT OUTER JOIN suburbs s ON p.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions_suburbs rs ON rs.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions r ON rs.region_id=r.id LEFT JOIN state st ON st.id=s.state_id UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN p.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('project_id|',p.id) WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('suburb_id|',s.id) ELSE '0' END AS id,s.title As SuburbName,s.postcode,st.abbr,CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.propertyname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(p.propertyname,', ') END,CASE WHEN s.title IS NULL THEN'' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(s.title), ' ') END,CASE WHEN st.abbr IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(st.abbr), ' ') END,CASE WHEN s.postcode IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(s.postcode, '') END) AS SearchTerm FROM properties p RIGHT OUTER JOIN suburbs s ON p.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions_suburbs rs ON rs.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions r ON rs.region_id=r.id LEFT JOIN state st ON st.id=s.state_id UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT('state_id|',id),'' As SuburbName,'' AS postcode,abbr,title AS SearchTerm FROM state) AS U WHERE 1 AND (SuburbName LIKE 'Newtown%' OR postcode='Newtown' OR LOWER(SearchTerm) LIKE LOWER('Newtown%') OR abbr LIKE 'Newtown%') ORDER BY SearchTerm ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

EXPLAIN RESULT

```
    id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    16657   Using where; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     p   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3    
2   DERIVED     s   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.p.suburb_id     1    
2   DERIVED     rs  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    383      
2   DERIVED     r   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.rs.region_id    1   Using index
2   DERIVED     st  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.s.state_id  1    
3   UNION   s   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    16640    
3   UNION   p   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3    
3   UNION   rs  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    383      
3   UNION   r   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.rs.region_id    1   Using index
3   UNION   st  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.s.state_id  1    
4   UNION   state   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8    
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3,4>    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

[Now] Showing rows 0 - 4 (5 total, Query took 4.6246 sec)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN p.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('project_id|',p.id) WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('suburb_id|',s.id) ELSE '0' END AS id,s.title As SuburbName,s.postcode,st.abbr,CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.propertyname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(p.propertyname,', ') END,CASE WHEN s.title IS NULL THEN'' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(s.title), ' ') END,CASE WHEN st.abbr IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(st.abbr), ' ') END,CASE WHEN s.postcode IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(s.postcode, '') END) AS SearchTerm FROM properties p LEFT OUTER JOIN suburbs s ON p.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions_suburbs rs ON rs.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions r ON rs.region_id=r.id LEFT JOIN state st ON st.id=s.state_id WHERE 1 AND (s.title LIKE 'Newtown%' OR postcode='Newtown' OR LOWER(CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.propertyname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(p.propertyname,', ') END,CASE WHEN s.title IS NULL THEN'' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(s.title), ' ') END,CASE WHEN st.abbr IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(st.abbr), ' ') END,CASE WHEN s.postcode IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(s.postcode, '') END)) LIKE LOWER('Newtown%') OR st.abbr LIKE 'Newtown%') UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN p.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('project_id|',p.id) WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('suburb_id|',s.id) ELSE '0' END AS id,s.title As SuburbName,s.postcode,st.abbr,CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.propertyname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(p.propertyname,', ') END,CASE WHEN s.title IS NULL THEN'' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(s.title), ' ') END,CASE WHEN st.abbr IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(st.abbr), ' ') END,CASE WHEN s.postcode IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(s.postcode, '') END) AS SearchTerm FROM properties p RIGHT OUTER JOIN suburbs s ON p.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions_suburbs rs ON rs.suburb_id=s.id LEFT JOIN regions r ON rs.region_id=r.id LEFT JOIN state st ON st.id=s.state_id WHERE 1 AND (s.title LIKE 'Newtown%' OR postcode='Newtown' OR LOWER(CONCAT(CASE WHEN p.propertyname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(p.propertyname,', ') END,CASE WHEN s.title IS NULL THEN'' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(s.title), ' ') END,CASE WHEN st.abbr IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(st.abbr), ' ') END,CASE WHEN s.postcode IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(s.postcode, '') END)) LIKE LOWER('Newtown%') OR st.abbr LIKE 'Newtown%') UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT('state_id|',id),'' As SuburbName,'' AS postcode,abbr,title AS SearchTerm FROM state WHERE 1 AND title LIKE 'Newtown%' ORDER BY SearchTerm ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

EXPLAIN RESULT

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     p   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3    
1   PRIMARY     s   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.p.suburb_id     1    
1   PRIMARY     rs  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    383      
1   PRIMARY     r   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.rs.region_id    1   Using index
1   PRIMARY     st  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.s.state_id  1   Using where
2   UNION   s   ALL     title_postcode  NULL    NULL    NULL    16640    
2   UNION   p   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3    
2   UNION   rs  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    383      
2   UNION   r   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.rs.region_id    1   Using index
2   UNION   st  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   residential.s.state_id  1   Using where
3   UNION   state   range   title   title   102     NULL    1   Using where
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union1,2,3>    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Using filesort
```

Comment: Show the `explain` result of the query. `explain select ...`

Comment: Please provide Db structure (diagram) in and explain what are you trying to do, So any one of us can give you optimized solution. Because some times you have to do more queries but it results much earlier than one big query

Comment: Table structures, purpose of query and Expalin result have been added.

Comment: Well, partial table structures... Is ID the PK of Properties table? Under what circumstances can it be NULL (other than as a result of the RIGHT JOIN)? And may I safely infer that some properties are not associated with a suburb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help here. I finally found the culprit that slown down my query.

I tried to remove bits by bits from my SQL statement and run it over and over. Finally after removing the following two LEFT JOIN parts,

```
       LEFT JOIN regions_suburbs rs
              ON rs.suburb_id = s.id
       LEFT JOIN regions r
              ON rs.region_id = r.id
```

it improves from

```
Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 4.8538 sec)
```

to

```
Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.2337 sec)
```

To acheive this I had to make some changes to databsae design. Initally, property table stores only suburb_id because we can get its region_id and state_id if we know suburb_id. To avoid joining regions_suburbs and regions table back, I am now storing state_id, region_id and suburb_id instead of only one suburb_id. In this we could take out two LEFT JOIN from the query and it improves the query response time tremendously by leveraging two additional column storage which is worth.

**EDIT:**
Creating some INDEX on the columns I am selecting grately improved the response time too.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it inside out.  Instead of computing everything you want and then seeing if 'Newtown%' is in each resulting piece, ...

1. For each *table* search the relevant fields for 'Newtown%'.
2. Join each of SELECT in Step 1 back to `properties` (assuming that is the focus of this dataset); get *just* properties's PRIMARY KEY.
3. UNION DISTINCT all of the SELECTs from Step 2.
4. *Now* JOIN to whatever tables are needed, and do the knarly CONCATs, etc to product the output -- based on the ids from Step 3.

Once you have done that, you can get some more performance if you are willing to use something other than `SearchTerm` in the ORDER BY.  I would suggest simply `properties.id`.  With that, you can do ORDER BYs in steps 2 and 3 to cut back on how much is shoveled from step to step.

(`OFFSET` will cause another issue when you have `UNION`s; we can address that separately.)